# How to create animated plot of curve depending on parameter in WolframAlpha?

Tags: plane-curves, wolfram-alpha

Is it possible to create in WolframAlpha an animated plot of a curve given by an equation, where some of the coefficients depend on the parameter (=on time)?

For example if I would like to have a plot $x^2+2xy+3y^2+x+y=t$, which would show for each $t$ one of [concentric ellipses](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=contour+plot+x%5E2%2B2xy%2B3y%5E2%2Bx%2By) and from the plot we could see how the curve changes when $t$ is changed. (The parameter $t$ stands for time.) Or a plot of $x^2+2xy-3y^2+x-y=t$, which could 
illustrate evolution of a [family of hyperbolas](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=contour+plot+x%5E2%2B2xy-3y%5E2%2Bx-y).

Or is something like this possible only if I [subscribe to the Pro version](http://www.wolframalpha.com/pro/)?

Comment: Maybe I should mention that according to [this discussion on meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10587/are-questions-related-to-using-wolfram-alpha-on-topic), questions about WA are on-topic on this iste.

Comment: Even if it is on-topic, I guess that you will get better help on the Mathematica SE site for this kind of question.

Comment: @mickep From what I read [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tags/wolfram-alpha-queries/info) and [here](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1066/sending-wolframalpha-questions-to-wolframcommunity) it seems that questions like this would be closed as off-topic on that site.

Comment: OK, I see. That's a pity. Good luck in finding a way (I was not able to, while trying a bit).

Comment: According to what I was told [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/21696152#21696152), it is not possible to create animations in WA. (At least not with the free version.)

Answer (score 0):

According to the help in Mathematica 10, you could do something like this:

`ListAnimate[Table[WolframAlpha[StringJoin["contour plot x^2+2xy+3y^2+x+y==", ToString[t]]], {t,0,5,1}]]`

This shows a plot for each of the values $t=0,1,2,3,4,5$.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not seem to work: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ListAnimate%5BTable%5BWolframAlpha%5BStringJoin%5B%22contour+plot+x%5E2%2B2xy%2B3y%5E2%2Bx%2By%3D%3D%22%2C+ToString%5Bt%5D%5D%5D%2C+%7Bt%2C0%2C5%2C1%7D%5D%5D (Or I'm doing something wrong.)

Comment: That command is for Mathematica 10. I do not think it is possible to create such interactive plots in WolframAlpha; at least, in the free version...